# Can we control the SSL version for ClientHello

Tags: tls

Can we control the SSL version for ClientHello (like passing the lesser version then maximum supported)?

I am using Java client to connect to App server. Currently my client is supporting TLSv1.0 and App server is supporting SSLV3, TLSV1.1 and TLSv1.2 but TLSv1.0 has been disabled due to its vulnerability to BEAST attack.

So I wanted to connect to App server via SSLv3 instead of TLSV1.0

Can I achieve the same with Java Client?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. At least in Firefox (I'm running 26.0).  Open a tab to about:config.  Filter for tls.version  and set the min/max appropriately. Here's the breakdown of the meaning of the [values](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security.tls.version.%2a).

You can also mess with the accepted cipher suites via options (filter about:config for: security.ssl3).

You can test your browser SSL/TLS options by visiting: [HowsMySSL.com](https://www.howsmyssl.com/)

Good luck.

(Of course, if, instead, you're looking for a general/OpenSSL answer, the API documentation is your friend. :-D )

Answer (score 1):

This question cannot be really answered without knowing what is the involved client software. The *client* decides what goes into the `ClientHello`. Some (most) Web browsers can be configured to use or not-use any specific version of SSL/TLS. For instance, with Firefox, you can use the `about:config` URL to access the internal configuration options, in particular `security.tls.version.min` and `security.tls.version.max`.

However, we can still stay that such an alteration *cannot* be forced from the outside (e.g. some firewall or proxy) because the handshake ends with control messages (called "`Finished`") whose contents are verified by the peer (the server verifies the contents of the `Finished` from the client, and vice versa); the contents are actually a hash value computed over the complete contents of all the previous handshake messages. This ensures that the client and server really saw the same messages, down to the last bit. If you alter a `ClientHello` in transit, then the `Finished` messages at the end of the connection will not match, and the handshake will not succeed.

(The generic term for forcing a SSL client and server to use a lower version than what they would both like is a *version rollback attack*; SSL/TLS includes effective protections against that, specifically the contents of the `Finished` messages.)

Comment: Hi Tom,

I am using Java client to connect to App server. Currently my client is supporting TLSv1.0 and App server is supporting SSLV3, TLSV1.1 and TLSv1.2 but TLSv1.0 has been disabled due to its vulnerability to BEAST attack.

So I wanted to connect to App server via SSLv3 instead of TLSV1.0

Can I achieve the same with Java Client.

Thanks !!

Regards,
Ashutosh Kejriwal

Comment: I am using Java 1.6. There is some constraint with Java 1.7

Comment: One may point out that SSL 3.0 is equally vulnerable to BEAST as TLS 1.0, so it makes little sense, on the server, to disable the latter and not the former.

Comment: In any case, if the server supports SSL 3.0 (but not TLS 1.0) and the client says "up to TLS 1.0" in its `ClientHello`, then the server should use SSL 3.0. The version specified in the `ClientHello` is the _maximum_ version supported by the client; it does not mean that the client would refuse any other version.

Comment: I agree Tom, this issue is specific here.

Comment: I agree Tom, this issue is specific here. When I send a clientHello with TLSv1.0, server is giving error but when I send clientHello with SSLv3.0, it's accepting.

I don't want to degrade my TLSv1.0 to SSLv3 at system level through "https.protocols".

I want to degrade it only for this specific server. I hope it will be more meaningful to you know.

So my question is, can I pass a ssl version for clientHello  manually through Java Client rather then the default one or it's own negotiation.

Thanks!!

Regards,
Ashutosh Kejriwal

Answer (score 0):

You can use `openssl` with the `s_client` option to initiate SSL/TLS connection. Doing so you can influence the protocol used with the appropriate parameters `-ssl2` `-ssl3` `-tls1` `-dtls1`. You can list the available options like this

```
 openssl s_client --help
 ...
 -ssl2         - just use SSLv2
 -ssl3         - just use SSLv3
 -tls1         - just use TLSv1
 -dtls1        - just use DTLSv1
 ...
```